# reduce size of an MCMC/ rjags object

Tags: r, bayesian, jags

I have recently started running more complicated Bayesian models in R using the rjags package. As model complexity has increased I have had to run longer chains to reach convergence for some parameters. Generally I will try a run at 20,000 and if this does not converge, use the update function to increase the chain length.

For simple models I can save the model object, and it is small enough to share easily (<50 Mb), however I have a few models that require chains around 800,000 in length to reach convergence which result in objects >100 Mb.

Is there a function or technique to reduce the size of these objects before I save them? I am familiar with the concept of thinning when starting the model, but am interested if there is a technique to "thin" the chains post-hoc.

Comment: This reads like a request for R code which is typically off topic here. You may be able to rephrase this, though, to emphasize the statistical issues here.

Comment: I have looked into the coding side of things and have not found a canned answer e.g. "use this function".  To me this seems like a question that splits the difference between code and stats. I am hoping that someone may have experience with a valid technique to address this, and I can then find a tool or write a function to use this technique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three thoughts:

1. That many samples until convergence sounds like there are issues with your model/priors. The diagnosis would require seeing the model -- and also more knowledge than I have. Some models are just hard, sometimes you can use tricks that make them more amenable, and sometimes you have an outright error.
2. Most MCMC samplers have a `thin=n` argument that says to only save every nth sample. I couldn't find it for `rjags` but I assume JAGS supports an option like that.
3. You might consider switching to `rstan` (directly, or via `rstanarm` or `brms`). Each iteration takes longer, but in general each iteration is less-correlated and of better quality, so it's not unusual to use 3-5K iterations rather than tens-of-thousands. (In particular, Stan is better at ridge-like distributions than other samplers. As an example of someone who switched to Stan and saw a huge improvement: [Managing high autocorrelation in MCMC](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162857/managing-high-autocorrelation-in-mcmc))

   The difference between Stan and JAGS is that JAGS (like BUGS) is a language to describe a model, while Stan is more executable. For example, a JAGS `for` is not an actual loop, but rather a plate specification, while in Stan a `for` actually is a for loop.

Comment: (+1) thinnin is the thin(g)!